# [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified GULP 4

Tags: node.js, gulp

I can not update the code with the gulp.series syntax...
when I run the below code,  I have the following error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Can anyone help me to convert this file in gulp version 4 ? 
Thanks in advance ! 
I can not update the code with the gulp.series syntax...
when I run the below code,  I have the following error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Can anyone help me to convert this file in gulp version 4 ? 
Thanks in advance !

```html
/**
 * Gulp file to automate the various tasks
 */

var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var csscomb = require('gulp-csscomb');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var del = require('del');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var htmlPrettify = require('gulp-html-prettify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
var gulpRun = require('gulp-run');
var gulpUtil = require('gulp-util');
var npmDist = require('gulp-npm-dist');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var useref = require('gulp-useref-plus');
var wait = require('gulp-wait');

// Define paths

var paths = {
    dist: {
        base: 'assets',
        img:  'assets/img',
        libs: 'assets/vendor'
    },
    base: {
        base: './',
        node: 'node_modules'
    },
    src: {
        base: './',
        css:  'assets/css',
        html: '**/*.html',
        img:  'assets/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)',
        js:   'assets/js/**/*.js',
        scss: 'assets/scss/**/*.scss'
    }
}

// Compile SCSS

gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.src.scss)
        .pipe(wait(500))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss([require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes')]))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['> 1%']
        }))
        .pipe(csscomb())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.src.css))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

// Minify CSS

gulp.task('minify:css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        paths.src.css + '/atmos.css'
    ])
        .pipe(cleanCss())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.base + '/css'))
});

// Minify JS

gulp.task('minify:js', function(cb) {
    return gulp.src([
        paths.src.base + 'assets/js/atmos.js'
    ])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.base + '/js'))
});

// Live reload

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: [paths.src.base, paths.base.base]
        },
    })
});

// Watch for changes

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'scss', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.src.scss, ['scss']);
    gulp.watch(paths.src.js, browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(paths.src.html, browserSync.reload);
}));



// Copy CSS

gulp.task('copy:css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        paths.src.base + 'assets/css/atmos.css'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.base + '/css'))
});

// Copy JS

gulp.task('copy:js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        paths.src.base + 'assets/js/atmos.js'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.base + '/js'))
});

// Build

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
    runSequence( 'scss', 'copy:css', 'copy:js', 'minify:js', 'minify:css',
        callback);
});

// Default

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence(['scss', 'browserSync', 'watch'],
        callback
    )
});
```

Comment: welcome to SOF. Can you please paste the whole stack trace

Comment: Read https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/complete-guide-upgrading-gulp-4/ and https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-to-gulp-4/

Comment: @sarmahdi done ! thanks